# php build new array from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have only worked with basics arrays and I have a simple array that I am passing into my php class from a ajax json call

```
"item": [ "4","3","6","5","7"]
```

I am trying to get into this array format where id is the above array and order starts at 0 and counts up ++1

I have tried a foreach loop in an array but I know that is not the way to do it.

```
$data = array(
    array('Page' => array('id' => 3, 'order' => 0)),
    array('Page' => array('id' => 4, 'order' => 1)),
    array('Page' => array('id' => 5, 'order' => 2)),
    array('Page' => array('id' => 6, 'order' => 3)),
    array('Page' => array('id' => 7, 'order' => 4)),
);
```

I have tried:

```
$data = array(
    foreach($this->request->data as $key => $value) {
    array('Page' => array('id' => $key, 'order' => 0)),
    };
);
```

Comment: Did you try doing the `foreach()` outside of the array and properly adding the items?

Comment: What do you want the array to look like **exactly**?

Comment: The same dudies here.. Keith did you note PHP warining there? It should tell something like `Unexpected :, expected ..` or stuff like that

Comment: The warning I get is syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ')'. I did try the foreach() outside the $data whci just duplicated it.

Comment: Yeah, you should have posted it here. And also answer what Xat asked

Comment: Try `$data = array();
        foreach($this->request->data as $key => $value) {
        $data[] = array('Page' => array('id' => $value, 'order' => $key)),
        };`

Comment: @kingkero - after some of the comments I've had on here today for trying to help people, I'm sorely tempted to do just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run a foreach inside an array like that. Try this:

```
$data = array();
foreach($this->request->data['item'] as $key => $value) {
   $data[] = array('Page' => array('id' => $value, 'order' => $key));
}
```

As a guess looking at your format I think you probably want to use `$value` instead of `$key` in `'id' => $key`

---

After chatting together and working through it this is the final version of the code that worked:

```
$data = array(); 
$raw = $this->request->data; 
$array = $raw['item']; 
$i = 0; 
foreach($array as $val) { 
    $data[] = array('Page' => array('id' => $val, 'order' => $i)); 
    $i++; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Styphon. I am getting an error syntax error, unexpected ',' on the third line of you code

Comment: Should have been a semi-colon at the end. As you had it in an array before I didn't notice you had a comma at the end ;)

Comment: yes sorry, I was getting a different error so didn't spot that. I get the array now but only one entry. I should see 5

Comment: @KeithPower That's probably because you set the order to 0 for all of them. Check my answer now, it should set the order dynamically.

Comment: the order should start at 0 and just keep counting up. The change in the code now gives me "Page": {
                "id": [
                    "4",
                    "3",
                    "6",
                    "5",
                    "7"
                ],
                "order": "item"
            } The previous code was closer to what I was looking for but just looped once

Comment: Then your array isn't in `$this->request->data`, it's in `$this->request->data['item']`, so try doing the foreach on that. You have run `json_decode` on the ajax response right?

Comment: I have changed to and I get this [{"Page": {"id": 0, "order": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "Page": {
                "id": 1,
                "order": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "Page": {
                "id": 2,
                "order": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "Page": {
                "id": 3,
                "order": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "Page": {
                "id": 4,
                "order": 0
            }
        }
    ] For id I am not getting the values. It is just counting up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55261/discussion-between-styphon-and-keith-power).